# Ошибка PHP: \Ds\Stack() класс не найден

Tags: php, объекты, стек

использую официальный пример работы с линейным стеком \Ds\Stack(): https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.ds-stack.php

```
$stack = new \Ds\Stack();

$stack->push("a");
$stack->push("b");
$stack->push("c");

var_dump($stack->pop());
var_dump($stack->pop());
var_dump($stack->pop());
```

выдаёт ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ds\Stack' not found in C:\OSPanel\domains\lab5.CD\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\lab5.CD\index.php on line 2

`$q = new SplStack();` работает

Только начинаю изучать стеки не понимаю почему не работает =( как исправить и в чём проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите использовать `\Ds\Stack()` вам нужно установить расширение `ext-ds` и модуль PECL ds. Хотя я советую использовать `SplStack()`, если вам не нужно использовать другие структуры из данного модуля. [Ссылка на репозиторий ext-ds](https://github.com/php-ds/ext-ds) там же можете прочитать инструкцию по установке

Comment: Спасибо, Стало попроще